# Trying to find the longest word in a file - Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that will find the longest word in a file and then print the line that it's on and the word. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but I'm only passing for an empty file.
Here's my code thus far:

```
def longest_word(file_name):
    data_file = open(file_name, "r")
    lst = [word.rstrip("\n")for word in data_file]
    if len(lst) == 0:
        print('its empty')
    else:
        return (max(len(word) for word in lst)+1)
```

Comment: What is the output when you pass a file with text in it? Is it throwing an error or you are not getting the correct output

Comment: It's not throwing an error. I'm just not getting the correct output.

Comment: If you are dealing with very long files, think in terms of generators as you could not necessarily load all your file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Note two things -

1. If the file is not empty you return the maximal length rather than
   n print it (comparing to the case the file is empty).
2. You return the length of the longest word and not the word itself.
3. See the code below which iterate all the words and find the longest one. I converted the list to set for efficiency.

   ```
   def longest_word(file_name):
       data_file = open(file_name, "r")
       lst = [word.rstrip("\n")for word in data_file]
       if len(lst) == 0:
           print('its empty')
       else:
           max_length = -1
           max_word = None
           for word in last:
               if len(word) > max_length:
                  max_length = len(word)
                  max_word = word
           print(max_word)
   ```